# Spring Cloud Config Server - User id and Password to connect to github

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I looked at the code for a number of spring cloud config servers in github repo and below are the 2 values that are provided as part of property file. I believe in order to connect to https end point of github , user id and password are also necessary. Could these perhaps be part of environment variables?

```
server.port=7070
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://
```

EDIT:

Below is the example that I saw in spring website. However in all the github repos within my enterprise I don't see userid and password being set as they are sensitive info. How could it be set or config server access github url , if uid / pwd is not provided in the property file?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
          username: trolley
          password: strongpassword
```

Comment: via environment variables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. for **public repository** there is no need to use *username* and *password* or other authorizations to get config properties, for **private repository** auth are required.
2. it is possible to set variable from enviroment which from os or java-system-property and command line. for precedence: **command-line-param > java-system-property > os-env > application.properties**.

So, for example what if i set property use command-line directly (which has highest precedence.) like:

`java -jar config-server.jar --spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=xxx --spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=xxx`

which contain all param in CI tools or whatever then managed by someone, you wouldn't see that in source code.

Comment: Thanks , this helps

Answer (score 2):

Easy Tip -

Go to github.com -> Developer settings -> Create Access Token, then create an access token with a read repo priviliage only. that way a private repository can be expose without giving plain text password!

Something like this -

spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=0371abshak3048sa8d81828488483sd302

Comment: The OP is asking how to secure the config server not how to access git in a secured manner

Comment: use reduced network visibility trick in order to secure config server, and add bootstrap properties to use alias name like - spring.cloud.config.uri=http://config/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use variables like this:

```
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${GIT_REPO_URL}
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=${GIT_USERNAME}
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=${GIT_TOKEN}
```

And set those env vars on any CI.
For example as secrets on GitHub Actions:

```
    - name: Build config-service
      env:
         GIT_REPO_URL: ${{ secrets.GIT_REPO_URL }}
         GIT_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.GIT_USERNAME }}
         GIT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}
```

And seems like you can't use password anymore to access GitHub, you need top pass GitHub token here `spring.cloud.config.server.git.password`

Comment: Note that when using a token a username isn't strictly needed. But you need to set the `username` property to something, otherwise you get an error ("Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered").